# Найти целое число в строке MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите с задачей
у меня есть поле tag с типом строка
Есть две строки в таблице

внутри 1 строки в поле tag значение [2,3,4]
внутри 2 строки в поле tag значение [22,90,100]

если я делаю запрос

```
SELECT * FROM app_tours WHERE (tags LIKE "%2%") ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

То база вернет мне две строки, потому как она найдет двойку в значении 22

Подскажите как решить этот вопрос как найти именно число в строке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from app_tours 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '2', '$');
```

Как пример использования:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT "[2,3,4]" as tags
UNION SELECT "[22,90,100]") as b WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '2', '$');
```

Возвращает
`[{tags: "[2,3,4]"}]`

Comment: Работает но как использовать для вывода нескольких результатов например
SELECT * from app_tours WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '2', '$') OR JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '90', '$')

Comment: Разобрался, нужно чтобы был тип поля Джисон а не текст тогда работает если несколько условий